# SQL query not reading date as string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, debugging, web

This piece of code works

```
$date = "12/09/2016";
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM someTable.forum_posts_queue where post_owner='admin' and post_create_time = '".$date."' order by post_id desc limit 0,1";
```

However, I wanted to set the date as a variable and pass it in as a string

```
$date = date("m/d/Y");
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM someTable.forum_posts_queue where post_owner='admin' and post_create_time = '".$date."' order by post_id desc limit 0,1";
```

This doesn't read the date as the same above, and doesn't understand the query.

Comment: what happens when you run the query?

Comment: MYSQL expects dates to be in the Logical format `YYYY-MM-DD` are you sure `$date = "12/09/2016";` works? The format `MM-DD-YYYY` isn't logical anywhere, its just the way Americans say a date and the confusion is something we call have to put up with

Comment: Yes! I stored it as a string that would match the syntax of the date("12/09/2016") and run a cron job to get the queued post for the day

Comment: @Rahul
I don't know how to debug inline but it's a valid sql query, but doesn't get the right result

Comment: @brosephBear you should use MySQL's built-in date/time functions. They will serve you well. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Final comment: Store dates as DATETIME or DATE or TIME or TIMESTAMP Then MYSQL does almost all the work for you.

Comment: I also tried (string)date("m/d/Y")

Comment: no, because I set up a queue where I write the date for the post to happen.

Comment: can I create a future timestamp from a string input? Right now I just use a text field.

Comment: Always use proper date fields, The presentation layer is where you cope with local presentation requirements.

Comment: read the comment carefully by @RiggsFolly. That should wipe out the issue

Comment: I tried to convert my input string to date as  $schedule = date_create($_POST['date']);
and insert but it said Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: @brosephBear, try to echo $schedule to see that the value of $schedule is the value that you expect...

Comment: yes, I did and its the same as the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```

Should solve your problem (assuming that the type of "post_create_time" field is of DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP).

Comment: This is the answer. Use this format for your dates in the database. If you don't like it, you will learn to.

Comment: Ok, that is helpful, but it was the fact that I was calling a string and checking to see if the current day was the string equivalence. Although, I solved it by standardizing it. I could have used a better answer of converting a date to string or the opposite of this: ` $schedule = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['date']);
 $schedule = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($schedule));`